# Match the innermost block (start to end, unless another block appears inside)

Tags: regex, pcre

I'm not quite sure if the title explains my problem so here i go. I'm trying to create a templatesystem in PHP. The syntax would look like this:

```
                #foreach(params):
                   <ul>
                        <li>Username: *{users_username}</li>
                        <li>ID: *{users_id}</li>
                        <li>Email: *{users_email}</li>
                        <li>Password: *{users_password}</li>
                        <li>Index: *{count}</li>
                        <li>Count: *{index}</li>
                  </ul>
                  #foreach(params):
                       <ul>
                           <li>Username: *{users_username}</li>
                           <li>ID: *{users_id}</li>
                           <li>Email: *{users_email}</li>
                           <li>Password: *{users_password}</li>
                           <li>Index: *{count}</li>
                          <li>Count: *{index}</li>
                       </ul>
                 #endforeach;
            #endforeach;
```

I want to start by matching the innermost block starting with: `#blockname(parameters):` and ending with `#endblockname;`. The regex should also capture the content of the block. I'm thinking this could be achieved by getting everything after `#blockname(parameters):` and before `#endblockname;` unless another `#blockname(parameters):` comes before.

I would then run the PHP preg_replace multiple times, each time removing another layer of blocks.

If you have questions, ask away.

EDIT: so far i have tried the following: `@[a-z]{1,}\([^)]*\):((?:(?!@[a-z]{1,}\([^)]*\):).)*?)@end[a-z]{1,};` which only work if no linebreaks occur.

Answer (score 3):

The following regex will match innermost blocks following the syntax you defined:

```
/
^[ \t]*[#]                       # start of line and indent up to "#"
(?<blockname>\w+)                # blockname (captured)
(?:[(](?<params>[^]]*)[)])?:     # text inside brackets (captured)
[ \t]*\n                         # and optional space to end of line

(?<body>(?>                      # get the body (captured)
    (?![ \t]*[#]\w)              #   if not followed by a block definition
    .*\n                         #   match the whole line
)*)

[ \t]*[#]end\g<blockname>;       # until it matches "#end" + the text captured in blockname
/mx
```

<kbd>[regex101 demo](https://regex101.com/r/mD5eM5/2)</kbd>

---

It uses a **[named group](http://www.regular-expressions.info/named.html)** to capture the blockname

```
(?<blockname>\w+)
```

and another that matches all lines from the body of the block, except if there's a line starting with another block definition (using a **[negative lookahead](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html)**).

```
(?<body>(?>
    (?![ \t]*[#]\w)
    .*\n
)*)
```

until it can match the end of the block, using a **[backreference to](http://www.regular-expressions.info/backref.html)** (the text we previously matched in) the named group

```
[#]end\g<blockname>;
```

---

This captures the text in `blockname`, `params` and `body`, in case you use this regex with `preg_match_all()` or `preg_replace_callback()`, you would conveniently get the matched text as:

```
preg_match_all($re, $str, $matches);

$matches["blockname"][matchNum]
$matches["params"][matchNum]
$matches["body"][matchNum]
```